# Postgres resource management

Tags: postgresql, memory, postgresql-9.3

I'm consolidating multiple Linux boxes running Postgres into one box.

Given the way Postgres handles resource utilization, would one single server service handling all the databases provide a much better performance than multiple server services (each one listening to different IP:port) running on the same host?

Thanks

Comment: Nobody will able to answer you without knowing about your databases some details, like how many connections they get, how much memory/temp disk space they use, how they are interconnected by queries/application logic and so on.  From a pure resource consumption the best thing to have is one physical machine for every single database but there are other factors, too.

Comment: Having one physical machine per database is not an option. They want to go exactly the other way around (Thermal issues on the datacenter).
The question I have is who would do a better job handling resources:
1) Postgres, or
2) Linux (with multiple Postgres server services running at the same time)

Comment: You'll need to provide a fair bit more info on what they propose to consolidate. Database sizes, machine sizes, workloads and utilisation levels.

Comment: Copied & pasted to http://serverfault.com/q/606497/102814.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, a single instance is more efficient, but has inferior performance isolation between databases.

If you want maximum throughput and best resource utilisation, put them all in a single instance. One busy DB will be able to affect other DBs more easily this way, especially when it comes to things like high rates of small write transactions. Features like async commit, commit delay, etc, help. If you group them all on one instance you'll also have to do any physical backups and streaming replication / PITR for the whole set of DBs, you can't isolate just one DB.

If you want to reduce the impact one busy/overloaded DB has on another DB, isolate them into their own instances and put each on a separate file system, perferably on separate underlying storage. You'll pay a price in wasted `shared_buffers` space, extra `fsync()`s, etc, and you'll find things like user management a major pain, but you'll be able to do streaming replication / physical backups of just one DB and you'll be more able to manage their relative resource allocations. If they're separate instances you can use things like `nice`, `ionice`, etc more effectively and can manage storage quotas somewhat better.

Comment: Thanks Craig, very illustrative answer.
Do you know if there is something like "nice" within Postgres?

Comment: @DiegoPuertas Not built-in. You can use OS tools, but you have to be aware of priority inversion problems with locking and that things like the WAL + bgwriter are shared. I have some funded work scheduled on this but it might slip because of other priorities, and even if I get it done it won't land before 9.5.